# How to install and use exiftool to get GPS information of a photo

Tags: photo, kali, gps, location, exiftool

I want to install exiftool and get a location information of a photo. please help.
thank you

Answer (score 2):

The instructions to download and install are [here](https://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/install.html#Unix).

To list the gps lat/long, use this command:
`exiftool -GPSLatitude -GPSLongitude FILESorDIRS`
replacing `FILESorDIRS` with the files and/or directories you wish to list.

To see all the gps tags, you can use a wildcard:
`exiftool -gps* FILESorDIRS`